# Metaplex SDK - Upload Metadata Devnet

Tags: metaplex, nft, devnet, metaplex-js

I am trying to use the new Metaplex JavaScript SDK to upload NFT metadata from my frontend. https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#uploadMetadata

Wallet context provider setup:

```
const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;
const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);
```

The metaplex initialization code in a context provider that looks like this:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet")); // TODO: check environment
const mx = Metaplex.make(connection).use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet)); // wallet = useWallet()
const auctionHouse = await mx.auctions().findAuctionHouseByAddress(new PublicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUCTIONHOUSE)).run();
```

And then from my minting component, I pull the metaplex context instance and call it to create the metadata after I upload image to IPFS and have all details:

```
const { mx } = mxCtx;
const uploadResult = await mx.nfts()
  .uploadMetadata({
    name, 
    description,
    image: file.href
  })
  .run();
```

I get the phantom wallet prompt that says "Estimated Changes: No changes impacting asset ownership found. Network Fee < 0.00001 SOL Transfer SOL to [https://solscan.io/address/DHyDV2ZjN3rB6qNGXS48dP5onfbZd3fAEz6C5HJwSqRD?cluster=devnet"](https://solscan.io/address/DHyDV2ZjN3rB6qNGXS48dP5onfbZd3fAEz6C5HJwSqRD?cluster=devnet%22)

I click on the Approve button in phantom wallet, and after a few seconds in the Dev Console I see the error response returned:

```
_app-fb5381fe6bf38b4c.js:2 POST https://node1.bundlr.network/account/balance/solana 500

Uncaught (in promise) Error: HTTP Error: Posting transaction 5peSoWQgvWej6EyqdKhB2TvWUXGLTzvJTsafBPQGP5yLT8MKpef6hshVQBfTxcwuVGe6R8T2ukMtPF61DXGjmpA9 information to the bundler: 500 Internal Server Error
```

An example of the transaction record pulled from the phantom wallet is here:
https://solscan.io/tx/5peSoWQgvWej6EyqdKhB2TvWUXGLTzvJTsafBPQGP5yLT8MKpef6hshVQBfTxcwuVGe6R8T2ukMtPF61DXGjmpA9?cluster=devnet

Has anyone run into this while using the Metaplex SDK? What am I doing wrong? Any advice or suggestion is greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: I made a tool that mints Metaplex NFTs on devnet quickly https://old.vicyyn.com/mint-metaplex-nft

Answer (score 1):

After adding a call to use `bundlrStorage` before the `uploadMetadata` call, was able to make a successful call to upload the metadata.

```
.use(bundlrStorage({
  address: 'https://devnet.bundlr.network',
  providerUrl: 'https://api.devnet.solana.com',
  timeout: 60000,
}))
```

txn: https://solscan.io/tx/4jkhkDafri3cruftYP2hCb4sQVJGYgPajk9TgnTmasVZbxwFuzzJyqW5hWgQnwv9ERdH68j4xwysb5gSh2rUMa47?cluster=devnet